# Obter usuário logado no Asp.Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Como eu faço para pegar o Usuário que está logado na classe ?

Estou tentando dessa forma:

```
public class Teste
{        
   private readonly UserManager<Usuario> _userManager;

   public Teste(UserManager<Usuario> userManager)
   {
      _userManager = userManager;
   }
   public async Task<Usuario> GetUser()
   {
      var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
      return user;
   }
}
```

Porem não está funcionando no Asp.Net Core 2.0:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você deve pegar esses valores dentro dos seus controllers.

Comment: deu certo, peguei os valores no controller e mandei pro objeto que ia usar, vlw

Comment: Amigo irei colocar como resposta, se puder pontuar como resposta válida agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tanto obter valor na classe ou no controle.

A resposta do **@Maycon F. Castro**, está errado, você pode sim, obter o nome do usuário ou a identificação usando `ClaimsPrincipal`, veja o exemplo abaixo:

**Class:**

```
public static class MinhaClasse
{
    public static string GetUserId(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
    {
        if (claimsPrincipal == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(claimsPrincipal));
        }
        return claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
    }

    public static string GetUserName(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
    {
        if (claimsPrincipal == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(claimsPrincipal));
        }
        return claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
    }
}
```

**HomeController:**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{    
    var id = Content(User.GetUserId()).Content; //"dd76f866-a04b-4517-ba1f-7bf35a1ae2c8"
    var name = Content(User.GetUserName()).Content; //matheusmiranda@hotmail.com

    return View();
}
```

***Fontes*** : [Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.content?view=aspnetcore-2.1), [ClaimsPrincipal](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Através de injeção de dependência, você pode ter acesso ao seu `HttpContext` em qualquer parte da aplicação que receba objetos por injeção. Basta injetar a interface `IHttpContextAccessor`.

```
public class Teste
{        
   private readonly UserManager<Usuario> _userManager;
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor

   public Teste(UserManager<Usuario> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
   {
      _userManager = userManager;
      _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
   }
   public async Task<Usuario> GetUser()
   {
      var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User);
      return user;
   }
}
```

Comment: Muito interessante, +1;

Answer (score 0):

**Complementando(Outra opção)...**

uma outra opção para pegar o usuário logado é fazer isso diretamente pelo `controller`

```
private readonly UserManager<Usuario> _userManager;
public SeuController(UserManager<Usuario> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    Usuariouser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apenas complementando com uma opção que pode ser usada apenas dentro de um `Controller`.

```
string currentUser = User.Identity.Name;
```

É possível também verificar se o usuário está em determinado `Role`:

```
if(User.IsInRole("nomeDoSeuRole"))
{
    // Seu código
}
```